# Is this question appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've recently found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043545/neural-networks-applied-to-graph-analysis). I'm waiting for the bounty period to end to vote to close it, however since I've found it, it accumulated nine upvotes. I don't understand: it's not a programming question, and it's not even properly formulated. The general idea is clear: "fix" graphs automatically, but the constraints are completely unclear. [The first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043545/neural-networks-applied-to-graph-analysis#comment40821886_26043545), and further discussion explains that:

> I think that the problem is not yet well defined. Why should it be a connection between v4 and v2? in your plot it does seem to be a cycle v2-V3-v5-V7-v4-V2, but if you represent V7 next to V6 and V4 bellow it, then you have a cycle V5-V6-V4-V7-V6. if V4 is always at that position and connected to v2, than is a mere problem of identifying if there is a connection between V2 and V4 and if not, reconnect –  [ASantosRibeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3651923/asantosribeiro)

Also the question is as vague as it gets, as it boils down to:

How to

> apply some kind of intelligence on a network topology
>   <sup>(quote from the question itself)</sup>

Am I wrong thinking that this is not a good question, or those upvotes are just because the question has some code and a picture (figuratively speaking)?

BTW: I do find the topic interesting, and surely this has potential of starting an interesting discussion, but definitely not on Stack Overflow (perhaps nor on any Stack Exchange site).

Comment: I sometimes flag such questions with an other flag explaining that i would like to close vote it but that it isn't possible due to the bounty. I'm not sure if that would fly here.

Comment: @lpapp Yeah :) It's a good thing, but I hope the OP won't get downvoted to oblivion ;0

Comment: That question looks way too broad for SO. If I had to speculate, people may have upvoted it because it looks like a very interesting problem (I personally think it is), and it's basically well written, with pretty pictures and everything. So they may overlook the fact that this is the wrong site for it.

Comment: [This bountied question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467792/qt-based-activex-works-well-in-x86-platform-target-but-not-in-x64) has no way to reproduce the issue either. It lacks code, explanation and all that. The only thing that it serves is to attract rep whores for the relative high bounty.

Comment: The Meta effect: http://puu.sh/dLda1/7a6c0cca32.jpg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think you are wrong. When I run into such a question I raise a custom flag explaining that the question should be closed but that the community cannot currently vote on it due to the bounty. **I make as good of a case that I can as to why it should be closed.** It usually results in a moderator closing the question. Sometimes the bounty is effectively cancelled. (I don't know what happens to the rep. Nor do I care much.)

> Am I wrong thinking that this is not a good question, or those upvotes are just because the question has some code and a picture (figuratively speaking)?

Upvoting does not require much reputation and consequently does not require much knowledge of the rules of SO. (Yes, I know there are some high rep users who also don't know (or willfully) ignore the rules.) So I would not take upvotes as reflecting any kind of conscious assertion that the question is fit for SO. Conversely, I'd expect most upvotes to be due to the fact that the question has some code, etc.

Comment: Didn't know moderators react to such a flag - it involves not purely administrative analysis and action. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I would say the more it involves domain-specific knowledge, the less likely the flag is going to result in a closure initiated by a moderator. The cases I run into tend to be clearly close-worthy.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, when one is not completely certain that they can make a compelling flag message for moderator to cancel bounty and close, bringing to meta for a more thorough discussion (like it was in this case) may be a viable option

Comment: The Meta effect: http://puu.sh/dLda1/7a6c0cca32.jpg